# Express "invalid input syntax for integer: when generating a csv

Tags: node.js, reactjs, api, express

I'm trying to generate a CSV file from the backend and serve it to my frontend for download.
The data is already in the frontend and I send it to the backend as JSON data and successfully generate the CSV file in the backend but I get a status 500 error with the response being `{"error":"invalid input syntax for integer: \"api\route\path""}` when the get request for the file on the frontend is called

Express API Code

```
import { Parser } from 'json2csv';

export default class AutomationController {
  static async postReport(req, res) {
    try {
      const fields = ['email', 'fellowName'];
      const report = req.body;
      const json2csvParser = new Parser({ fields });
      const csv = json2csvParser.parse(report);
      const path = `downloads/Reports.csv`;
      fs.writeFile(path, csv, (err) => {
        if (err) {
          throw err;
        } else {
          res.download(path);
        }
      });
    } catch (e) {

    }
  }

  static async getReport(req, res) {
    try {
      return res.status(200).sendFile(`downloads/Reports.csv`);
    } catch (err) {
      return res.status(500).json({ error: err.message });
    }
  }
}
}
```

Backend Routes

```
router.get('/fetchReport', automationController.getReport);
router.post('/downloadReport', automationController.postReport);
```

React Frontend

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { saveAs } from 'file-saver';

 createAndDownloadPDF = () => {
    const { automationData } = this.state;
    axios.post('http://localhost:8000/api/v1/automations/downloadReport', automationData)
      .then(() => axios.get('http://localhost:8000/api/v1/automations/fetchReport', { responseType: 'blob' }))
      .then((res) => {
        const csvBlob = new Blob([res.data], { type: 'text/csv' });
        saveAs(csvBlob, 'report.csv');
      });
  };
```

Comment: Have you tried `res.sendFile('downloads/Reports.csv', {root: __dirname});`?

Comment: @JBaczuk Yes I have

Comment: I've also tried setting headers using `res.set('Content-Type', 'application/octet-stream');` and 
```res.set({
        'Content-Disposition': 'attachment;',
        'Content-Type': 'text/csv',
      });

 ```